# resetting number counter while using multiple bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, setcounter

I have multiple bibliographies (one for each chapter of my dissertation). Everything works great using these commands in the preamble:

---

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% Modify the following line to match your school
% Available options include `Harvard`, `Princeton`, and `NYU`.
\documentclass[School=Harvard]{Dissertate}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}  % Changes the heading to \section
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\let\chapter\section}{}{} % Ensures the heading is treated as a section
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\vspace*{-3.5em}}{}{}  % Adjust the -1em value as needed
```

---

I have a `bibliography.tex` for each chapter and am using this code at the end of each chapter:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}

\section{References}

\bibliographystyle{achemso}

\bibliography{bibliographies/ref_chap1}
```

How do I reset the counter such that each Reference section for each chapter starts numbering from 1 instead of having it continuously number from the previous section?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more information about what's in each of the `bibliograpy.tex` files. Incidentally, is the impression correct that that the same filename, viz., `bibliography.tex`, is used in the separate chapters?

Comment: Does the problem depend on `Dissertate.cls`? Because that's not a class most of us have.